# Is 'on arrival of something' idiomatic?

Tags: expressions

I stumbled upon something a bit unsure when writing a short instructional sentence as below;

> **On arrival of a luggage**, keep the luggage in the storeroom and notify the receiver of it.

By the bold-faced phrase, I meant when a luggage has arrived here, but I'm not sure this 'on *something* of *something*' structure is commonly used.

Comment: The phrase _on arrival of_ is indeed acceptable, but so is _upon arrival of_.

Comment: On arrival is fine. On arrival of a luggage is not. A present for you: When luggage arrives, put it in the storage room and notify the owner that it has arrived.  You own your luggage or bags. You are not its recipient.

Comment: To rephrase what I think Lambie is saying, **luggage** is a mass noun, so you don't say "a luggage".  It's just "luggage" or "a piece of luggage".

Comment: @stangdon Yes, and I am rewriting the sentence also. There is no recipient here. Luggage has an owner.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the bold phrase is quite common, but the correct pattern for the bold text is "on the *something* of *something*", so you need a definite article **the** in front of arrival. In addition, [luggage](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/luggage) is uncountable, so you should not put **a** in front of it.

I would also suggest that "the receiver of it" is not very elegant: better to say "the [recipient](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/recipient)".

You might also want to consider replacing **keep** with **place** or **put**, as placing the luggage in the store room is the only thing that happens immediately on the arrival of baggage. Keeping it in the storeroom is what happens for some time, after it has been placed there. The refined sentence would be:

> On the arrival of luggage, place the luggage in the storeroom and notify the recipient.

Comment: It's not recipient. It's the owner.

Comment: @Lambie, if you read the OP's text, it refers to "the receiver of it". Let's not assume that the recipient is also the owner.

Comment: This is about lost luggage at an airport or train station. The OP hasn't written the sentence correctly. If the luggage arrives at some place, there has been no recipient. There is only the owner of the luggage who will then come and pick it up when he or she is notified.

Comment: Answer is completely correct, point by point. One could use also `store` instead of `keep`, maybe even `register`.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the precise context, it is hard to be sure but "On the arrival of luggage..." does not sound to me like anything anyone would actually say, as distinct from what a bureaucrat might write. It seems to imply that luggage just appears, as if from nowhere. "Notify" is an especially bureaucratic word that no-one uses in normal speech.
If it were me, I should say "When luggage arrives, put it in the storeroom and tell the owner it is there."

Answer (score 0):

On arrival of a luggage, keep the luggage in the storeroom and notify the receiver of it.=not well phrased.

When lost luggage arrives, put it in the storage room and notify its owner.

storeroom is for a stop, not lost luggage. Lost luggage is stored in a storage room. A storeroom is where you keep stores (supplies).

Comment: There is no mention of **lost** or **owner** in the question....

Comment: It is implied. Because no one would store luggage that is "received by a recipient" in a "storeroom". The OP is trying to write a "short instrutional sentence".